# Getting Null with findComponent method?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Here is the Java code i added

```
 public void collapseTreeById(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {  
        String treeId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("treeId");  
        UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();  
        UITree tree = (UITree)viewRoot.findComponent(treeId);  
        tree.setToggleType(SwitchType.server);;  
        }
```

and Jsf page changes

```
<a4j:commandLink actionListener="#{inventoriesBean.collapseTreeById}"
                                value="collapse" render="treeServType">
                                <f:param value="treeServType" name="treeId" />
                            </a4j:commandLink>
```

But i am getting Null in this line `UITree tree = (UITree)viewRoot.findComponent(treeId);`

Here `treeServType` is id of **Tree**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then that simply means that the component with given `findComponent` [search expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent-java.lang.String-) does not exist in the component tree. You seem to have passed the sole component ID and you are searching inside `UIViewRoot` (the root of the component tree). This will fail if the target component is by itself actually inside a [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) component, such as `<h:form>`.

If you can't or don't want to change the `findComponent` search expression to represent an absolute component ID like `formId:treeId`, and it has the same `NamingContainer` parent as that command link, then you should search via that naming container parent instead.

```
String treeId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("treeId");  
UIComponent namingContainerParent = event.getComponent().getNamingContainer(); 
UITree tree = (UITree) namingContainerParent.findComponent(treeId); 
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks @baluc i tried with this way and it worked

  `public void collapseTreeById(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {  
        String treeId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("treeId");  
        UITree tree = (UITree)event.getComponent().findComponent(treeId);  
        tree.setToggleType(SwitchType.server);;  
        }  `

Comment: Only one question not related to this can i reload whole richfaces tree from bean now?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455507/how-to-recreate-a-component-after-clicking-a-command-button-in-jsf

Comment: You're welcome. No idea, I don't do RichFaces, so I can't answer off top of head. Maybe I will spend more time and investigate if there's a bounty.

Comment: But you are already a master of JSF and richfaces not > JSF its a Child of JSF

Comment: Your concrete problem is RichFaces specific, not JSF specific. Answer may be JSF-general, but that would be hacky if there was a RichFaces specific way.

Comment: Ok can you tell me how to recreate a whole component in JSF when clicking any button?